# Transfer value of <select> into <textarea> before submitting with JavaScript

Tags: javascript, html, button, textarea, submit

Let's say I have the next HTML code:

```html
<textarea class="message" type="textarea" name="message" id="message" placeholder="Send us your message"> </textarea>

<select name="cars">
  <option class="car">Volvo</option>
  <option class="car">Saab</option>
  <option class="car">Fiat</option>
  <option class="car">Audi</option>
</select>

<button type="submit" class="button">Send!</button>
```

So, using JavaScript, I want to achieve the next thing:
 1. when the button is clicked, to store the selected value inside option
 2. to transfer that value inside of the textarea
 3. after the first two steps, to submit the informations;

Thanks in advance, if you don't understand what am I exactly asking for, I'll be available for further discussion.
Extra info: Maybe i should have been a bit more specific. I'm working on a contact form, that send a message to a specific e-mail. My goal is to, just before submitting, put the stored value of option into the textarea, that is then sent as a message to that e-mail. I hope this helps.

Comment: You know you're getting a new page after submitting the form ..?

Comment: I'm aware of that. I didn't want to go into much details. I'm working on a contact form that is submittet to an email as a message, so I'm not worried about the page reloading after that. Thank you for your response.

Comment: Then you've to add the new placeholder at the server-side code, so that it is visible on the new page.

Comment: My bad, now I have edited my post. The placeholder isn't relevant, I made a typo. The goal is to put the value of option inside of textarea, that is sent as a message to the e-mail.

Comment: Attach an onsubmit event to the form, and set the value of the textarea in the handler function.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Something like this should get you started:

```
<script>
    function transferSelect() {
        document.getElementById('message').value += document.getElementById('cars').value;
    }
</script>

<textarea class="message" type="textarea" name="message" id="message" placeholder="Send us your message"> </textarea>

<select id="cars" name="cars">
  <option class="car">Volvo</option>
  <option class="car">Saab</option>
  <option class="car">Fiat</option>
  <option class="car">Audi</option>
</select>

<button type="submit" onclick="transferSelect();" class="button">Send!</button>
```

Comment: Thank you very much! And then I should put an event listener, that calls this function?
This way, due to the += the value of textarea won't be changed, only the value of cars will be added to it? Thanks again.

Comment: The onclick event is already added to the button in the sample I gave, so you don't need to add a separate listener. And yes, the way I've done it, the value of the select is appended to the end; you can adapt that however you see fit to achieve the end result you want

Comment: Thank you very much. Probably saved me few hours of trouble. I'm new at JavaScript, just finished DOM fundamentals. So i've had an idea to do it that way, but wasn't sure what was the right approach. Anyways, thanks again!

Comment: Glad I could help. Just so you know, if I answered your question, you can [mark my answer as accepted](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work/5235#5235)

Comment: Okay, I didn't know that. There you go- just did that :)